# The action didnot return a valid dictionary in ibm watson

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my dictionary which is coming as response

```
{
  "body": {
    "Status": "Alive"
  }
}
```

But when i am trying to fetch  the status by

```
print('new_dict :',new_dict)
```

it is giving response as

```
new_dict : {'Status': 'Alive'}"
```

How this extra double quote is coming.
Has anyone faced this issue. How to solve this.

Comment: How can i remove this extra double quotes

Comment: Please add [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and whatever you have tried to solve that problem. This way you'll have better chances of getting an answer

Comment: What does this have to do with ibm watson?

Comment: Please post your relevant code, what is new_dict and how did you get it ?

Comment: nothing with ibm watson . I am making an ibm cloud function which will use this response.

Comment: So , is it possible to remove that double quotes at end

Comment: This is a get request i am doing here ` r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)  
body=r.json()
    new_dict = {'Status' :body[0]['status']} ` Now here when i am printing new_dict it is giving me extra double quotes at end @MooingRawr @ dfundako

Comment: edit your code into your question with proper format please.

Comment: this is the code -  `code`   r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) body=r.json() new_dict = {'Status' :body[0]['status']} `code`     Now here when i am printing new_dict. It is giving me extra double quotes at end    @MooingRawr @ dfundako

Comment: this is the code -  `r = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) body=r.json() new_dict = {'Status' :body[0]['status']}`   Now here when i am printing new_dict. It is giving me extra double quotes at end @MooingRawr @ dfundako

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a valid option for your task?

```
[print(f"new_dict: {k} : {v}") for k, v in new_dict['body'].items()]
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/LPTHW$ python3.7 dictquotes.py 
> new_dict: Status : Alive
> ```